# how do I create the number entered into 6 consecutive calls in java?

Tags: java, recursion

I am having trouble implementing a consecutive call here. For example I want the user to only enter a number once, say 40.. and have 6 consecutive calls.

```java
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Main
{
    public static int count = 0;

    public static int fibonacci(int a)
    {
        count +=1;
        if (a<=1)
        {
            return a;
        }
        return fibonacci(a-1)+fibonacci(a-2);
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n =6;
        for (int i=1; i<= n; ++i){
            long start=new Date().getTime();
            Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
            int a= s.nextInt();

            System.out.println("This Fibonacci number =" +fibonacci(a));
            long end=new Date().getTime();
            System.out.println("seconds used for this calculation ="+((end-start)/1000));
        }
    }
}
```

this is what I have so far.

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: You can pass the `int` value `a` to as many functions as you like. But perhaps I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I'm not sure that I know exactly what you're asking, but it sounds like you only want to run the three lines from `Scanner s= ...` down to `int a= s.nextInt();` once.  You could try picking them up and moving them to before the beginning of the `for` loop.

Comment: When it runs it currently asks the user to enter a number six times, I need it to only ask the user once and if they enter for example 40, to increment 6 times, ex. 41, 42,43,45

Comment: So, start with my suggestion, then adjust things if you don't get the result you want.

Comment: You should also be aware that an `int` is only just large enough to hold the 46th Fibonacci number.  If you're going to try to calculate a bigger Fibonacci number than that, you'll need `long` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Move your Scanner and int a outside the for loop. Currently, the Scanner is being run 6 consecutive times.

Answer (score 1):

This will run everything inside the brackets 6 times. If you want only the second part to be run 6 times, confine it to that.

Also you never defined start, so your timing code won't work at all.

```
     public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int n =6;
        

       long start=new Date().getTime();
       Scanner s=new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("Enter a number: ");
       int a= s.nextInt();
       for (int i=1; i<= n; ++i){
            long start=new Date().getTime();
            System.out.println("This Fibonacci number =" +fibonacci(a));
            long end=new Date().getTime();
            System.out.println("seconds used for this calculation ="+((end-start)/1000));

        }

    }
```